# Using new[] where size is result of a message call causes crash

Tags: objective-c++, clang++

I have some Objective-C++ code which dynamically allocates space for an array of Objective-C object pointers. The size is computed by an Objective-C message call:

```
ItemCell **rawCells = new ItemCell*[[self cellCount]];
```

This code eventually causes a segfault. The similar code

```
ItemCell **rawCells = (ItemCell**)std::malloc([self cellCount] * (sizeof *rawCells));
```

works just fine. What's going on here?

Comment: Since the question is answered, it should be closed.

Comment: @albatross created an answer with your answer in it.  +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copied from poster's answer (he lacks the karma to answer himself, so he put it in the question), and marked as community wiki (because copy/paste shouldn't earn me karma):

The problem is that `[[self cellCount]]` is treated as a [C++11 attribute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Attributes) and ignored, since the compiler doesn't recognize it. The result is that the line effectively becomes

```
ItemCell **rawCells = new ItemCell*;
```

which doesn't allocate enough storage. I confirmed this in gdb - the argument to `new` is 8, the size of a single pointer.

The most compact way to solve this is to insert an extra pair of parentheses to prevent the compiler from recognizing `[[` and `]]` as attribute syntax:

```
ItemCell **rawCells = new ItemCell*[([self cellCount])];
```

You can also store the result of `[self cellCount]` in a local variable and refer to that in the `new[]` call.

Comment: Also, note that, in this case, you can use the dot syntax `self.cellCount`, resulting in `new ItemCell*[self.cellCount]`, which also parses fine. This won't work for more complex method calls, though.